# Is there any why in "Laravel" to update a newly added functionality?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, content-management-system, updates

I have a laravel setup on the server and another is on my dev server so is there any command or anyway like WordPress on single click it will update the files with newly added code. Can we do the same thing in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear. It does not make sense to compare the autoupdate of a blog system with a plain framework. Your question can be interpreted into three ways:

## Major Framework Upgrades 5.6 -> 5.7

Here your upgrade the framework itself. According https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade you have to edit your `composer.json` file and change the key `laravel/framework` to `5.7.*` (if you want to upgrade to the current stable version). Afterwards you need to call `composer update` to pull all the upgraded dependencies and follow the upgrade steps in the above link.

## Minor Framework Updates 5.6.2 -> 5.6.3

Here you just need to call `composer update`.

## Updating your production server version from dev server version

There are plenty of choices:

- Push the files via rsync from one server to the other
- Use a centralized GIT Repository where you push to the dev server and pull from the production server
- Use a deployment script like [Deployer](https://deployer.org)
- Use a Continuous Integration service

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions. 
The best one would be to have a GIT repository for your project.

Comment: Yes, that, one is the best the best solution but I would like to create my own update server. Is that possible?
I want to do some changes to laravel setup and all my clients should update from my server.

Comment: you can make a repository for the vendor folder too. that way you wont need the `composer update`